# SUMIFS is retaining Zero

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

In the Sheet "Allocation tool", it has a column "Available hours based on project dates" which has SUMIFS formula. How ever I try it retains Zero '0'

I am unable to understand if this is because the date lists are having another column reference or something else. Can I know how to change the formula and if not possible to write a formula in cell for this type of use case can I get help with macros

Uploaded file here: https://easyupload.io/lib8ql

```
=SUMIFS($F8:$L8:$R8:$X8:$AD8:$AJ8:$AP8:$AV8:$BB8:$BH8:$BN8:$BT8:$BZ8:$CF8:$CL8:$CR8:$CX8:$DD8:$DJ8:$DP8:$DV8:$EB8:$EH8:$EN8:$ET8:$EZ8:$FF8:$FL8:$FR8:$FX8:$GD8,$F$6:$L$6:$R$6:$X$6:$AD$6:$AJ$6:$AP$6:$AV$6:$BB$6:$BH$6:$BN$6:$BT$6:$BZ$6:$CF$6:$CL$6:$CR$6:$CX$6:$DD$6:$DJ$6:$DP$6:$DV$6:$EB$6:$EH$6:$EN$6:$ET$6:$EZ$6:$FF$6:$FL$6:$FR$6:$FX$6:$GD$6,"=>"&$G$3,$F$6:$L$6:$R$6:$X$6:$AD$6:$AJ$6:$AP$6:$AV$6:$BB$6:$BH$6:$BN$6:$BT$6:$BZ$6:$CF$6:$CL$6:$CR$6:$CX$6:$DD$6:$DJ$6:$DP$6:$DV$6:$EB$6:$EH$6:$EN$6:$ET$6:$EZ$6:$FF$6:$FL$6:$FR$6:$FX$6:$GD$6,"<="&$H$3)
```

Comment: Your dates in row 6 are not being recognized as dates. Actually, if you do something easy like `F6+1`, it will raise an error value, when it should return `2nd April`. In Excel, dates are numbers, but in this case, because they are not being recognized as dates, Excel can't resolve `"=>"&$G$3` so it becomes 0

Comment: Thanks for your time, I made sure to right click and change the format to dates (although it did not work), Also the dates are being taken from another sheet "Associate_Skills" with the formula "=Associate_Skills!M1" since the dates in Associate_Skills will keep changing  ever month. Can you suggest any alternative

Comment: @Shankar Please make sure you put example data whithin the question. According [ask] eveything that is needed to understand or reproduce your issue needs to be in the question itself. Linking files is not helpful because they will disappear after a while and then the question is usless for future readers. Also people are unlikely to download files from suspicious sources. Reading [mcve] might also help to improve your question.

Comment: Even if you change the cell format, the value you are getting from sheet `Associate_Skills` is a string, not a date. Consider using the VALUE function when getting them (but you will need to update other formulas that use that date as string)

Comment: Thanks for all the information, will try that...Also since I am new to stack overflow, I am still learning guidelines and how to ask question in better way, Thanks again